# How does `do_new_mount_fc()` mount real file systems like ext4?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, mount, vfs

In relatively old Linux kernel source codes, the `do_new_mount()` will call `vfs_kern_mount()`, which will finally do `mount_fs()`. And this function will call the real file system's function like below

```c
struct dentry *
mount_fs(struct file_system_type *type, int flags, const char *name, void *data)
{
    struct dentry *root;
    struct super_block *sb;
......
    root = type->mount(type, flags, name, data);
......
    sb = root->d_sb;
......
}
```

But in relatively new Linux kernel source code, the `do_new_mount()` will call [`do_new_mount_fc()`](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/fs/namespace.c.html#do_new_mount_fc) instead, and I can not find how this function call the real file system's mount function like above.

Can you tell me how it works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find the "usual" function calls because of the recent transition to the [new Filesystem Mount API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mount_api.txt) through "filesystem context". You can find more info in the relevant (quite massive) [patchwork](https://patchwork.kernel.org/cover/10820153/).

I'm not going to explain the whole thing as the kernel documentation that I linked above should already give a pretty good explanation (and I also am no Linux FS internals expert).

The "filesystem context" is basically a structure containing useful information that is passed around and updated incrementally as needed. So what happens now is that the [`vfs_get_tree()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/super.c#L1536) function is responsible for creating the mountable root of the filesystem, and saving it in the [`fs_context`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/include/linux/fs_context.h#L90) structure that is then passed to [`do_new_mount_fc()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/namespace.c#L2734) and used to do the actual mount.

```
(*) int vfs_get_tree(struct fs_context *fc);

     Get or create the mountable root and superblock, using the parameters in
     the filesystem context to select/configure the superblock.  This invokes
     the ->get_tree() method.
```

So now in [`do_new_mount()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/namespace.c#L2775) you see that function being called right *before* `do_new_mount_fc()`:

```c
    fc = fs_context_for_mount(type, sb_flags);
    put_filesystem(type);
    if (IS_ERR(fc))
        return PTR_ERR(fc);

    if (subtype)
        err = vfs_parse_fs_string(fc, "subtype",
                      subtype, strlen(subtype));
    if (!err && name)
        err = vfs_parse_fs_string(fc, "source", name, strlen(name));
    if (!err)
        err = parse_monolithic_mount_data(fc, data);
    if (!err && !mount_capable(fc))
        err = -EPERM;
    if (!err)
        err = vfs_get_tree(fc); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
    if (!err)
        err = do_new_mount_fc(fc, path, mnt_flags);

    put_fs_context(fc);
    return err;
}
```

The `vfs_get_tree()` function calls `fc->ops->get_tree()` which is the method responsible for creating `root` (if it doesn't already exist) and assigning it to `fc->root`.

```c
    error = fc->ops->get_tree(fc); // Here fc->root gets assigned.
    if (error < 0)
        return error;
```

The transition to this new API is still not complete for all filesystems. For the filesystems that still use the old API (for example ext4), the `fs_context_for_mount()` function (called at the beginning in `do_new_mount()`) creates the filesystem context through `alloc_fs_context()`, which checks whether or not the filesystem supports the new API, and if not it [uses a default legacy version of the filesystem context operations](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/fs_context.c#L295) (in fact, you can also see the comment in this last link which says *"TODO: Make all filesystems support this unconditionally"*).

For `get_tree()`, the legacy version is [`legacy_get_tree()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/fs_context.c#L616), which indeed does exacly what you would expect calling `fc->fs_type->mount(...)`.

```c
/*
 * Get a mountable root with the legacy mount command.
 */
static int legacy_get_tree(struct fs_context *fc)
{
    struct legacy_fs_context *ctx = fc->fs_private;
    struct super_block *sb;
    struct dentry *root;

    root = fc->fs_type->mount(fc->fs_type, fc->sb_flags,
                      fc->source, ctx->legacy_data);
    if (IS_ERR(root))
        return PTR_ERR(root);

    sb = root->d_sb;
    BUG_ON(!sb);

    fc->root = root;
    return 0;
}
```

Sooner or later, all filesystems will be updated to use the new API with filesystem context, those `legacy_*` functions will be removed completely and we will see a `init_fs_context` method in the [ext4 `file_system_type`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/fs/ext4/super.c#L6169).